# AWKPATH in windows is not loading resources (gawk 4.2)

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

I am running gawk 4.2 on a Windows 7 machine. I've tried setting up the `AWKPATH`[environmental variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/AWKPATH-Variable.html#AWKPATH-Variable) to `@include` some reusable pieces of scripts in my running gawk programs.
This is what is happening so far: the content in `AWKPATH` does not appear to be loaded: indeed when running my script I get:

```
gawk -f test.awk
gawk: test.awk:1: error: can't open source file 'getopt.awk' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I've tried pasting the same root for the scripts to `@include` in the `Path` system variable in Windows and the error was not prompted.

So far, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/973265/how-to-run-the-awk-command-in-windows-7) is the best matching question I found. However, it is already answered and the OP was using wrong syntax in that example.

I've downloaded gawk from ezywinports.

Source of `test.awk` is

```
@include "getopt.awk"
```

Since the variable `AWKPATH` was not created by gawk installation, I went on and create it myself - see attached picture. This folder is not on the same physical memory unit as the gawk install folder - linked to using `Path` windows var.

[image: Creating new variable on Windows 7]

Comment: So what is your `AWKPATH` actually set to? Please [edit] the question to include this.

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks for your feedback. I've added new information to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I am running gawk 4.2.1 downloaded from gnuwin32.org on Windows 10.  I have a similar problem.  When I use

```
set AWKPATH=/foo/bar
```

`awk` no longer finds script files in the current directory; i.e. `awk -f script.awk` fails to find `script.awk` in the current directory.  However, if I use

```
set AWKPATH=.:/foo/bar
```

then it *does* find scripts in the current directory.  I also can confirm that `AWKPATH` is being read in properly, because if I run this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["AWKPATH"] }'
```

I get the current `AWKPATH` setting.  If I use this setting (note backslashes and drive letter):

```
set AWKPATH=.:c:\foo\bar
```

the path search fails if I am running out of another drive (not C:), but it *does work* if I am on the C: drive.  If I omit the drive letter, the behavior is the same.  So, it looks like gawk does not handle drive letters properly, and you have to use backslashes as path separators.

Since I only have two drives that I commonly work out of, I duplicated the path I use in `AWKPATH` on both drives.  It is a pain to keep in sync, but it works. I hope this helps make awk a little more useful.